# Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.168.10.105, port: 25;

Tags: java, spring, jsp

hello friends i am trying to send email through jsp using eclipse but Following Error is Occurred .Internet is Connected to Compute but i cant understand the Concept of SMTP connect to Localhost.....

Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.168.10.105, port: 25;

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: above code i'm writing in jsp but it will give an error

Answer (score 2):

That's because the computer at 192.168.10.105 isn't running an SMTP server on port 25, or possibly a firewall is blocking a connection to it.

Comment: But How to Connect computer to SMTP